# How can i make background image show in mobile version of my code after using media query?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, background-image, front-end-optimization

I am a beginner learning HTML and CSS. I'm currently working on a project and I am utilizing media query. I have design the desktop version first because that looks easier to me. So why designing the mobile version, I don't why the mobile version is not showing the background image (and the pat to background image is very correct). I have tried my best and that is why I have decided to come on the platform to ask. Here's my code, please I want to know my mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <!--fonts styles-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Stats preview card component</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="container">

    <div class="first">
    <!--container for background image-->
    </div>

    <div class="second">
    <h1>Get <span>insights</span> that help your business grow.</h1>
    <p>Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer 
    experience, and overall efficiency.</p>
    <div class="stats">
      <dl>
        <div>
          <dt>10k+</dt>
          <dd>companies</dd>
        </div>

        <div>
          <dt>314</dt>
          <dd>templates</dd>
        </div>

        <div>
          <dt>12M+</dt>
          <dd>queries</dd>
        </div>

      </dl>
   </div>
   </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/* Base styles */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    font-size: 15px;
}
/*Card Styles*/
body {
    background-color:hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

main {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 1.5em;
    background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    margin: 8.5em auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.first {
    background-image:url('images/image-header-desktop.jpg');
    background-color:  hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    order: 1;
}
.second {
    padding: 3em;
}

h1 {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    width: 350px;
}

h1 > span {
    color:  hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}

p {
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
    margin-top: 1em;
    width: 400px;

    font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;

    line-height: 1.4;

}

dl {
    margin-top: 3em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
dl dt {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);

    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

dl dd {
    font-variant-caps: all-petite-caps;
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
}

/*media query styles */
@media(max-width:480px) {
    body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }
    main {
        width: 100%;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .first {
        background-image: url('images/image-header-mobile.jpg');
        background-color:  hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
        background-blend-mode: multiply;
    }


}
```

Please any help would be very appreciated.

I want to the background image to show in the mobile version of the code but it wasn't showing

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You have to give the `.first` a `min-height` for the image to show up.
You can tweak around with the value for your needs.</strike>

On desktop there's a certain space where the content (with height) can be visible. The `min-height` is for that "space" to be increased on mobile, because it was 0, and to be responsive, but you may define a simple `height` instead.

The orientation on mobile is usually portrait. The content is vertically positioned not horizontally. So, it makes better sens to apply a style that adapts to that.

Practically, we have to change the style from columns (horizontal) to rows (vertical).

That is, we add `grid-template-columns: auto;` (or better yet: `grid-template-columns: initial;`) to reset the "horizontal" value and add `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;` to define the vertical position.

The `auto` is the default state of the `grid-template-columns`, which when we put under `480px` media query, changes the inherited value, that was `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr`. Then we have to define the `main` element's new state with the `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;`, as can be seen here below:

```css
/* Base styles */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 15px;
}


/*Card Styles*/

body {
  background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1.5em;
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 8.5em auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.first {
  background-image: url('images/image-header-desktop.jpg');
  background-color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  order: 1;
}

.second {
  padding: 3em;
}

h1 {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  width: 350px;
}

h1>span {
  color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}

p {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 400px;
  font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

dl {
  margin-top: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

dl dt {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

dl dd {
  font-variant-caps: all-petite-caps;
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
}


/*media query styles */

@media(max-width:480px) {
  body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  main {
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: auto; /*to disable the inheritance*/
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .first {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300'); /*for demonstration purpose, can be anything else*/
    background-color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    /*min-height: 300px;*/
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <!--fonts styles-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Frontend Mentor | Stats preview card component</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">

    <div class="first">
      <!--container for background image-->
    </div>

    <div class="second">
      <h1>Get <span>insights</span> that help your business grow.</h1>
      <p>Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.</p>
      <div class="stats">
        <dl>
          <div>
            <dt>10k+</dt>
            <dd>companies</dd>
          </div>

          <div>
            <dt>314</dt>
            <dd>templates</dd>
          </div>

          <div>
            <dt>12M+</dt>
            <dd>queries</dd>
          </div>

        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But in the desktop version, I didn't used any min-height and it works why is it not working for the mobile version? Also must it be min-height why not other property like height?

Comment: You're very welcome. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I still don't get it Sir. I didn't just want to apply the fix but to learn from it

Comment: I've updated my answer to better suit your curiosity. I hope it makes better sense now. Adding the `height` is just a cosmetic fix, it's just not the right solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I first read through the updated solution, I was like what is the essence of adding grid-template-columns since the value we're using is "auto".But when I tried it without grid-template-columns: auto, the image is not showing but adding grid-template-columns:auto makes the image to appear. Please Sir, can you explain the reason for this, don't mind my inquisitiveness?

Comment: You're very welcome. I've updated my answer. It's okay to be inquisitive here. 